# How to fetch data objects using web service in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have a relational database where two tables are linked by a key. Depending on a search criteria in the parent table, the web service will return a list consisting of child table records. 
For example, if I have the parent table as "Version" with a column v_type and primary key v_id which references child table "Reference" with primary key ref_id and foreign key v_id. I need to fetch the list of records of table type "Reference".

1. How do I parse the list obtained?
2. How do I write the template and view?

A very simple example or syntax will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start by looking at [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/), that is where all database relational questions do get simple answers/solutions.